# TCP sequence number and ACK number

Tags: tcp, packet

Is the TCP sequence number just the ACK number + bytes received? Is it different when doing the 3-way handshake?

Answer (score 4):

From [TCP Connection Establishment Sequence Number Synchronization and Parameter Exchange](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionEstablishmentSequenceNumberSynchroniz-2.htm) :

> Once each device has chosen its ISN,
>   it sends this value to the other
>   device in the Sequence Number field in
>   its initial SYN message. The device
>   receiving the SYN responds with an ACK
>   message acknowledging the SYN (which
>   may also contain its own SYN, as in
>   step #2 of the three-way handshake).
>   In the ACK message, the Acknowledgment
>   Number field is set to the value of
>   the ISN received from the other device
>   plus one. This represents the next
>   sequence number the device expects to
>   receive from its peer; the ISN
>   actually thus represents the sequence
>   number of the last byte received
>   (fictitious in this case, since the
>   connection is new and nothing yet has
>   been received).

Comment: It only adds 1 when handshaking, but not during data transfer?